# What branch of the Math can help me with this?

Tags: random, entropy

I would love to focus on the branches of the Math that can help me with:

- generation of entropy, i suppose that most of the works are based on statistic since even a big part of the cryptographic world starts from this and is tested with the help of the statistic. But i do not wont to generate confusion, with entropy i mean to fake *randomness*
- creating structures programmatically and via a procedural way, like the classic Voronoi for example, but in N dimensions and with boundaries, for example generating a structure, a building, a road, an entire city, you get the point.

What is the big topic of the Math that can help me with this?

Comment: Please give your question a more meaningful title, e.g. "What branches of mathematics treat the generation of entropy and procedural structure generation?" - and it's also better to ask disjunct question separately...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Dynamical systems, more precisely: Ergodic theory. See [Introduction to ergodic theory](http://books.google.fr/books?id=ZT1xJSCdG30C&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Ya. G. Sinai or [Ya. B. Pesin's books](http://www.math.psu.edu/pesin/).

2) Fractal geometry. You can refer to [Fractal Geometry](http://eu.wiley.com//legacy/wileychi/fractal/) by Kenneth Falconer.

You can also see [Chaos and Fractals: New Frontiers of Science](http://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=jVpS_u0Lg4gC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=chaos+and+fractals+new+frontiers+of+science&ots=oMVexUKfna&sig=v41JhfWtSl-aW038UJxvCgFG3IM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=chaos%20and%20fractals%20new%20frontiers%20of%20science&f=false) (more elementary) by Heinz-Otto Peitgen, Hartmut Jürgens and Dietmar Saupe.

For programming, see [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/terrain/index.php3?fault), [here](http://research.cs.tamu.edu/keyser/Papers/GECCO2005.pdf) or [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.116.266).

Notice that these two branches are strongly linked.

Comment: thanks, can you also suggest some reference for this? maybe some good books? maybe oriented to the programming world?